Incorrect execution of the isna() method
I load my pre-prepared df dataset and look at the first 5 values using head():
df = pd.read_excel(\\United.xlsx")
display(df.head())

Using df.isna().sum(), I am trying to look at the total number of skips in the dataset.

However, when I apply df.isna().count(), 122 missing values are found in the dataset:

The dataset is small and consists entirely of numbers in each column:

So I'm pretty sure there are no omissions in the dataset.What can I do to get rid of non-existent skips in my dataset?
I tried removing missing values with dropna(): df.dropna(inplace=True) and also using fillna() to fill the gaps with a value of 0: df.fillna(0) but none of the above worked.

Hi, welcome to SO! Please don't post pictures of your data; instead create a [mre]. E.g., use something like df.head().to_dict() and post between triple backticks (```).

You're misunderstanding the result of df.isna(). It's a df with bool values (True or False). As integers, these are 1 and 0 respectively. So, if your overall sum is 0, you have zero NaN values: there's nothing to drop or fill. df.isna().count() is simply counting all your True and False values. Doing that will always lead to a count that equals the length of your df for each column, regardless of whether you have NaN values or not. The values counted are bools.

So what am I supposed to do in the end? How to work with such values if I want to input them to a function or a loop in the future?

That is way too general a question to answer. I was merely explaining that your current df doesn't have any NaN values, so that df.dropna won't drop anything and df.fillna won't fill anything. But if future dfs do have NaN values, both those methods can be used to deal with them. Whether that makes sense all depends on the kind of calculations, manipulations, etc. you want to do.
